# SML doesn't acknowledge ord or chr

Tags: ml

I'm using this example from ["Gentle Intro to ML"](http://www.soc.napier.ac.uk/course-notes/sml/tut1.htm)

```
 fun incFirst s = chr(ord s + 1) ^ substring(s, 1, size s -1);
```

But my "Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 [built: Tue Oct 22 14:04:11 2013]" doesn't like it.

> Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]

I can't even do this:

```
> ord "c";
```

without getting an error

> Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]

It doesn't recognize

```
load "Char";
```

either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `ord #"c"` because `"c"` is a string and `#"c"` is a character.

Your function has two problems:

1. Trying to glue together a character and a string using ^, which operates only on strings
2. Trying to use `ord` on a string

An ugly solution is this:

```
fun incFirst s = 
  Char.toString(chr(ord(String.sub(s,0)) + 1)) ^ substring(s, 1, size s -1);
```

I think you could probably make a prettier solution using `explode` and `implode` and a `let` block with a pattern match but I don't remember enough SML syntax off the top of my head to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. BTW, is there a good ML hyperspec with examples?

Comment: There's no hyperspec, but you can read the [SML Basis](http://sml-family.org/Basis/) documentation online.